# match with overlapping - only 3 chars but not 4 - regex

Tags: python, regex

i want to write a regex that will give me all chars that are in between exactly 3 digits. for example:
`111a333b444` will return `a` and `b`.  however, `1111a333b444` will return only `b` because there are more than 3 digits to the left of `a`.
because there is an issue of overlapping here i used a look ahead regex such as:
`matches = re.finditer(r'(?=([\d]{3}(.){1}[\d]{3}))',str)`  but in the second example above it also matches `111a333`.

anyone has an idea for a regex that will match?

thanks a lot

Comment: The `{1}` and the square brackets around `\d` are superfluous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
(?<=(?<!\d)\d{3})[^\d]+(?=\d{3}(?!\d))
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?312ta)

Comment: can u please explain the brackets on the first ?<=  ? i mean why doesn't (?<!\d)(?=\d{3}(.){1}\d{3})(?!\d) doesn't work ?